# How to display price of one Bitcoin on website in PHP?

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, php

Firstly, I know  this is a duplicate post but from what I can find all of the others are using the MtGox price (redundant now).

I was wondering - what is the current best way to display the price of one litecoin and one bitcoin in USD using PHP?

Comment: First example in linked question has a PHP example connecting to BitPay's rate API. Which is possibly better to use than exchanges. The basic gist is using PHP to read JSON from a url. See [how to Get JSON object from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url)

Comment: See the question that Jacob Torba suggested, I have added an answer there that might suite you.